# Can I use Javascript to build a list of an html elements members?

Tags: javascript, html, autohotkey

I am having issues looking up and correctly using javascript to interact with different html elements. In order to test and discover what will work for me more efficiently, I would like to be able to directly build a list of all of the methods and properties that work with an element I am trying to work with ("div" currently).

Something like:

```
element_to_test:="div"
loop % element_to_test.properties.length {
    property%a_index%:=element_to_test.properties[1].name
}
```

And the same for methods. I am using Autohotkey to automate many things so that is the syntax I use for interacting with the html dom. I use com and the iwebbrowser interface to interact with the web pages but I can use javascript via the iwebbrowser interface if I need to.

Is this possible?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Currently I am trying to click on an image. When I wrote this I was trying to navigate down from a div element to a input element by using getelementsbyclassname(classname). Autohotkey or internet explorer doesn't work with that method though and so I wanted to trouble shoot. Now I am seeing the .click() doesn't work on an img element even though with my mouse I can click it. The variability between different sources online added with the complexity of using autohotkey as my scripting language makes me really want a method to just test syntax and attributes directly.

Comment: IE9+ supports `getElementsByClassName()`; you are aware that JS is case-sensitive?

Comment: IE9 does but I think all the headers on the pages I work with have <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8,chrome=1"/>. JS is case-sensitive but Autohotkey isn't.

Comment: Either way, you are asking an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I don't understand what you're doing in either this question or your comment.

Comment: I have always solved my own problems eventually. My issue that I haven't solved yet (my real problem why I am here) is that I would like to write a script that when I give it an html element on a page, builds a list of all the properties and methods than work given a specific webpage. This would be extremely helpful and is the only thing I want help with.

Comment: Ex: `var img = document.createElement('img'); for (var p in img) { console.log(p); }` will list all of the prototype (and otherwise) properties and methods for an `<img />` element. Is that what you're looking for? The reason I say this is an XY problem is that I cannot imagine the _problem_ to which this list is the _solution_.

Comment: If that works, it is exactly what I am  looking for. Ideally I will be able to adapt that to autohotkey and I will be a happy man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my comment example as an answer:

```
var img = document.createElement('img'); 
for (var p in img) { console.log(p); }
```

This will log all the `img` properties, including everything in the `Element` and `Object` prototypes. You could do the same for any specific node.

Comment: This helps me with validating what my browser/webpage combination can do, but it would also help to know what limitations autohotkey throws into the mix. An autohotkey script that does something similar would be best.